# count of one column in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

How can I calculate the count of one column in Linq. for example:

```
select count(productid) from products
```

How will i write it in linq.

Is it like this?

```
var query = (from p in context.products select p).count()
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
var count = context.Products.Count(p => p.ProductId != null);
```

That's assuming I understand the point of you wanting to specify `ProductId` in the count part. It's pretty unusual for there *not* to be a ProductId in a Product row though. If you just want the number of rows at all, just use:

```
var count = context.Products.Count();
```

If you're after *distinct* values, you'd do something like:

```
var count = context.Products.Select(p => p.ProductId)
                            .Distinct()
                            .Count();
```

Comment: What if I want to use from notation instead of extension method notation ?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow: Well you can't use query expressions for the Count call itself. You could use `(from p in context.Products where p.ProductId != null select p).Count()` for the first, or `(from p in context.Products select p.ProductId).Distinct().Count()` for the second - but for queries like that I'd prefer extension methods.